# How to retrieve the original mathematical expressions from some sort of scripts?

Tags: notebooks, formatting, scripting

I quit my Mathematica notebook session mid-computation. When I reopen it, the mathematical expression disappeared leaving something like

```
Cell[BoxData[

 RowBox[{

  RowBox[{"f", "[", "t_", "]"}], ":=", " ", 

  RowBox[{

   RowBox[{

    RowBox[{

     RowBox[{"(", 

      RowBox[{"t", "-", "t1"}], ")"}], "/", 

     RowBox[{"(", 

      RowBox[{"t2", "-", "t1"}], ")"}]}],
```

Is there any way to salvage the original expression from this script-like thing?

Comment: I have sometimes successfully recovered corrupt notebooks using `AuthorTools` using the approach described [here](https://support.wolfram.com/12423?src=mathematica).

Comment: @TimLaska: Thank you. It does not seem to succeed. It is OK.

Comment: If they are not cut like in your example you can use `MakeExpression` to get an expression or `RawBoxes` / `NotebookWrite`to just make a valid cell. Here's an example: `RawBoxes@RowBox[{RowBox[{"f", "[", "t_", "]"}], ":=", " ", 
   RowBox[{RowBox[{RowBox[{RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"t", "-", "t1"}], 
           ")"}], "/", 
         RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"t2", "-", "t1"}], ")"}]}]}]}]}]` but I added missing brackets.